# General guidelines to self-organized task allocation within a Microservice

Tags: kubernetes, microservices

I have some general problems/questions regarding self managed Microservices (in Kubernetes).

**The Situation:**

I have a provider (Discord API) for my desired state, which tells me the count (or multiples of the count) of sharded connections (websocket -> stateful in some way) I should establish with the provider.

Currently a have a "monolithic" microservice (it can't be deployed in an autoscaling service and has to be stateful), which determines the count of connections i should have and a factor based on the currently active pods, that can establish a connection to this API.

It further (by heartbeating and updating the connection target of all those pods) manages the state of every pod and achieves this target configuration.

It also handles the case of a pod being removed from the service and a change of target configuration, by rolling out the updated target and only after updating the target discontinuing the old connections.

**The Cons:**

1. This does not in any way resemble a good microservice architecture
2. A failure of the manager (even when persisting the current state in a cache or db of some sort) results in the target of the target provider not being achieved and maybe one of the pods having a failure without graceful handling of the manager

**The Pros:**

1. Its "easy" to understand and maintain a centrally managed system
2. There is no case (assuming a running manager system) where a pod can fail and it wont be handled -> connection resumed on another pod

**My Plan:**

I would like this websocket connection pods to manage themselves in some way.

Theoretically there has to be a way in which a "swarm" (swarm here is just a descriptive word for pods within a service) can determine a swarm wide accepted target.

The tasks to achieve this target (or change of target) should then be allocated across the swarm by the swarm itself.

Every failure of a member of the swarm has to be recognized, and the now unhandled tasks (in my case websocket connections) have to be resumed on different members of the swarm.

Also updates of the target have to be rolled out across the swarm in a distinct manner, retaining the tasks for the old target till all tasks for the new target are handled.

**My ideas so far:**

As a general syncing point a cache like redis or a db like mongodb could be used.
Here the current target (and the old target, for creating earlier mentioned smooth target changes) could be stored, along with all tasks that have to be handled to achieve this desired target.

This should be relatively easy to set up and also a "voting process" for the current target could be possible - if even necessary (every swarm member checks the current target of the target provider and the target that is determined by most of the swarm members is set as the vote outcome).

But now we face the problem already mentioned in the pros for the managed system, I currently cant think of a way the failure of a swarm member can be recognized and managed by the swarm consistently.

How should a failure be determined without a constant exchange between swarm members, which i think should be avoided because of the:

- swarms should operate entirely target driven and interact with each other as litte as possible
- kubernetes itself isn't really designed to have easy intra service communication

Every contribution, idea or further question here helps.

My tech stack would be but isn't limited to:
Java with Micronaut for the application
Grpc as the only exchange protocol
Kubernetes as the orchestrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're on the JVM, you could use Akka Cluster to take care of failure detection between the pods (even in Kubernetes, though there's some care needed with service meshes to exempt the pod-to-pod communications from being routed through the mesh) and use (as one of many possibilities for this) Distributed Data's implementations of CRDTs to distribute state (in this case the target) among the pods.

This wouldn't require you to use Akka HTTP or Akka's gRPC implementations, so you could still use Micronaut for external interactions.  It would effectively create a stateful self-organizing service which presents to Kubernetes as a regular stateless service.

If for some reason Akka isn't appealing, looking through the code and docs for its failure detection (phi-accrual) might provide some ideas for implementing a failure detector using (e.g.) periodic updates to a DB.

Disclaimer: I am employed by Lightbend, which provides commercial support for Akka and employs or has employed at some point most of the contributors to and maintainers of Akka.